In what way were Stuart court masques examples of neoplatonic idealism?
In his introduction to Women Beware Women and Other Plays (Oxford University Press, 1999, page ix), Richard Dutton writes,

It seems unlikely that Thomas Middleton would have shared the neo-Platonic idealism of the Stuart court masques, extravagant celebrations of the court and its values.

The context is a discussion of the play Women Beware Women (which is not a court masque), about which Dutton says that (emphasis mine),

Middleton was here imitating the effect (if not the staging) of the actual court masque, where a change of scene or of perspective—both literally possible in the complex stages Inigo Jones created at court—could reveal a new and higher truth, implicitly relegating everything that has gone before to the realm of inadequate human perception.

The concept of a "higher truth" can be easily linked to Plato (hence the upward pointing finger in Raphael's The School of Athens), and the same is true "inadequate human perception": this is one way in which the allegory of the cave can be interpreted.
But the idea of a higher truth is not unique to Plato; it can also be found in Christian theology, a subject that king James VI (of Scotland) and I (of England) took interest in, even if it was mainly for political reasons. The idea of Christianity as higher truth can be found, for example, in James Orr's essay The Christian View of God and the World:

No duty is more imperative on the Christian teacher than that of showing that instead of Christianity being simply one theory among the rest, it is really the higher truth which is the synthesis and completion of all the other, that view which, rejecting the error, takes up the vitalising elements in all other systems and religions, and unites them into a living organism with Christ as head.

In addition, Plato was no fan literature and the arts. What we (and artists) see in the world is not reality itself but merely imitations of the "Forms" or "Ideas" that constitute reality (see Platonic idealism), and by imitating these imitations, art is twice removed from reality. As a consequence, it is not obvious how literature could reveal a "higher truth" in the sense of Plato's definition of reality.
Based on this, my questions are the following:

Does neoplatonism or any neoplatonic philosopher (as opposed to platonism itself) explain how literature might "reveal a new and higher truth", even though that seems to contradict what Plato thought? (Does Aristotle's view on art play a role in this?)
Is there any philosophical or literary theory from the English renaissance that discusses the relevance of neoplatonism to literature in general or even court masques in particular?

(Thomas Middleton also wrote masques.)

tl;dr

Yes
Yes, generally speaking; with regard to masques in particular, I'm not aware.

Deets
Neoplatonism traces back to the 3rd century CE philosopher Plotinus. In the Renaissance setting, however, the term refers to the specific blend of Christian theology and Platonic idealism characteristic of thinkers such as Marsilio Ficino and Giovanni Pico della Mirandola, who developed Plotinus's ideas in the context of humanism, the renewal of interest in classical antiquity. Neoplatonists argued that the study of the ancients was fully compatible with the revealed truth of Christianity. Since everything emanates from the divine Idea, even classical myth must include the divine. The stories and personages of classical mythology could thus be read allegorically as symbolizing the higher truths of theology and ethics. This attitude substantially underwrote the revival of classical learning that defines the Renaissance.
The emphasis on allegory was not confined to reading. It also extended to artistic endeavor. By creating beauty, artists could represent the true and the good, thereby using the particular to figure the eternal. Such a transcendental move was natural to allegory, wherein characters and narrative represent abstract ideals with a moral purpose. Allegory is typically associated with heroic poetry, such as the two great epics of the English Renaissance: Spenser's The Faerie Queene and Milton's Paradise Lost. But court masques, with their symbolic figures and their blending of poetry, spectacle, music, and dance, were also inherently allegorical.
These allegorical figures could be fantastically elaborate. Ben Jonson's Hymenæi (1606), written for the marriage of the Earl of Essex and Lady Frances Howard, includes inter alia the figure of Juno, the Roman goddess of marriage. Describing her, Jonson writes:

Juno, sitting in a throne, supported by two beautiful peacocks: her attire rich, and like a queen, a white diadem on her head, from whence descended a veil, and that bound with a fascia of several color'd silks, set with all sorts of jewels, and raised in the top with lilies and roses: in her right hand she held a sceptre, in the other a timbrel, at her golden feet the hide of a lion was placed: round about her sat the spirits of air in several colors, making music: above her the region of fire, with a continual motion, was seen to whirl circularly, and Jupiter standing in the top (figuring the heaven) brandishing his thunder: beneath her the rainbow, Iris, and on the two sides, eight ladies attired richly, who represented her powers, as she is the governess of marriage.
Jonson, Ben. Hymenæi; or, the Solemnities of Masque and Barriers at a Marriage. 1606. HTML etext by Anniina Jokinen, March 2003. Accessed at luminarium.org 26 July 2024.

John Meagher observes of this representation:

Jonson contrives, with the aid of the devices of the scene and in the poetical presentation, to present Juno not as an abstraction or a mere figure for marriage but as an authentic deity, with all the glory appropriate to a goddess—with all the glory bequeathed her by Neoplatonized mythography.
 Meagher, John C. Method and Meaning in Jonson's Masques. Notre Dame, IN: U Notre Dame P, 1966. p. 48.

Thus, the artistic practice of Jacobean masque writers such as Jonson show Neoplatonic underpinnings in their use of spectacle for allegorical purposes. Further, Neoplatonic ideas about the efficacy of poetry for revealing virtue and truth inform the literary theory of the English Renaissance as well. The most celebrated of such works is of course Sidney's A Defence of Poetry, aka The Defence of Poesie and An Apologie for Poetrie. Sidney slyly claims that Plato is himself a poet:

And truly even Plato, whosoever well considereth shall find that in the body of his work, though the inside and strength were philosophy, the skin, as it were, and beauty depended most of poetry: for all standeth upon dialogues, wherein he feigneth many honest burgesses of Athens to speak of such matters, that, if they had been set on the rack, they would never have confessed them, besides his poetical describing the circumstances of their meetings, as the well ordering of a banquet, the delicacy of a walk, with interlacing mere tales, as Gyges' ring and others, which who knoweth not to be flowers of poetry did never walk into Apollo's garden.
Sidney, Philip. A Defence of Poetry. 1595. Ed., intro., and notes J. A. van Dorsten. Oxford: Oxford UP, 1966. Accessed at archive.org 26 July 2024. pp. 19–20.

Sidney's discussion of the epic mode again invokes Plato, and exemplifies the Neoplatonic claim that the beauty made manifest through literature draws the reader to virtue:

There rests the Heroical—whose very name (I think) should daunt all backbiters: for by what conceit can a tongue be directed to speak evil of that which draweth with him no less champions than Achilles, Cyrus, Aeneas, Turnus, Tydeus, and Rinaldo?—who doth not only teach and move to a truth, but teacheth and moveth to the most high and excellent truth; who maketh magnanimity and justice shine through all misty fearfulness and foggy desires; who, if the saying of Plato and Tully be true, that who could see virtue would be wonderfully ravished with the love of her beauty—this man sets her out to make her more lovely in her holiday apparel, to the eye of any that will deign not to disdain until they understand.
ibid., p. 47.

Sidney turns to Neoplatonism once more to answer Plato's own charge against poetry. He claims that what Plato cautions against is not so much poetry as the abuse thereof. This abuse rests in "wrong opinions of the gods, making light tales of that unspotted essence":

Who list may read in Plutarch the discourses of Isis and Osiris, of the cause why oracles ceased, of the divine providence, and see whether the theology of that nation stood not upon such dreams which the poets indeed superstitiously observed—and truly (since they had not the light of Christ) did much better in it than the philosophers, who, shaking off superstition, brought in atheism. Plato therefore (whose authority I had much rather justly construe than unjustly resist) meant not in general of poets, in those words of which Julius Scaliger saith Qua auctoritate barbari quidam atque hispidi abuti velint ad poetas e republica exigendos*; but only meant to drive out those wrong opinions of the Deity (whereof now, without further law, Christianity hath taken away all the hurtful belief) perchance (as he thought) nourished by the then esteemed poets. And a man need go no further than to Plato himself to know his meaning: who, in his dialogue called Ion, giveth high and rightly divine commendation unto poetry.
ibid., pp. 59–60.
*  "whose authority some barbarians and rascals would have abused in order to expel poets from the republic." The quotation is from Book I of Julius Caesar Scaliger's Poetices libri septem or Seven Books on Poetics, 1561.

In Sidney's view, then, the Neoplatonic reconciliation between Platonism and Christianity rendered superfluous Plato's strictures against poetry.
Conclusion
Renaissance Neoplatonists held that Plato's idealism was congruent with Christian theology. They believed that the beauty of art derived from its representations of eternal truth, and that the experience of such beauty drew humans closer to that truth. Allegorical reading was therefore the chief interpretive strategy they adopted toward classical works. Likewise, English Renaissance writers often used allegory in their work. Masques in particular are allegorical almost by definition, certainly by design; Jonson's Hymenæi furnishes an example. Theoretical discussions during this period about the nature and purpose of literature also are suffused with Neoplatonic ideas, as can be seen in the most prominent of such works in the English language, Sidney's A Defence of Poetry.

Thanks a lot for this answer! Now I'm beating myself up for not having read Sidney's A Defence of Poetry.

yw. Everyone should read Sidney's A Defence of Poetry. And everything else he wrote.
